# Can't access Sales or Sales Console Apps

Tags: lightning-apps, sales-cloud, sales

I'm a System Administrator.

My permission set license assignments are:

- Sales Console
- Sales User

Via permission sets, I have the following assigned apps:

- Sales (standard__LightningSales)
- Sales (standard__Sales)   Sales
- Console (standard__LightningSalesConsole)

I also assigned the following permissions:

- Sales Cloud User
- Sales Console

In app manager:

Sales (LightningSales) and Sales Console (LightningSalesConsole) have:

- App Type = Lightning
- Visible in Lightning Experience = Checked

In both apps, under User Profiles, the System Administrator profile is selected.

Anything else that I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access and use a Lightning console app, users must have the Lightning Console User permission and their profile must be added to the Lightning console app.

[image]

Available in: Lightning Experience
Available in: Essentials, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

Lightning console apps are available for an extra cost to users with Salesforce Platform user licenses for certain products. Some restrictions apply.